# Visio Web part not displaying picture

Tags: error, visio

When loading a Visio drawing using the Visio Web access part I get a dialog box that only says "Error"

Comment: Have you used visio before in the same environment?

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup the visio-service correct?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj900483(v=office.15).aspx